# Mercator projection - Use existing equation to solve for degrees

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, projection, geodesy

[Mercator projection: problem with latitude formula](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/20686)

The answer to the previous question explains how to determine the correct pixel position at a given degree on a Mercator map. For example plug in a given map width in pixels and a given latitude in degrees and it will spit out the correct pixel position. I've tested it with dozens of possible degrees and it always comes back with the right answer. It's awesome.

This is the equation. The 2 variables are `mapWidth` ($w$) and `degreePosition` ($d$) and the output is `pixelPosition` ($p$).

$$p=\frac w{2\pi}\ln\tan\left(\frac\pi4+\frac d2\cdot\frac\pi{180}\right)$$

However I need to solve this equation for `degreePosition` and my brain has reached the breaking point. After multiple attempts I can not figure out what to do. `degreePosition` is buried inside a natural log and tangent and I can't figure out how to get it out to one side.

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac w{2\pi} \ln\tan\left(\frac\pi4
                            + \frac d2\cdot\frac\pi{180}\right) &= p\\
\ln\tan\left(\frac\pi4 + \frac d2\cdot\frac\pi{180}\right)
  &= \frac{2\pi p}w \\
\tan\left(\frac\pi4 + \frac d2\cdot\frac\pi{180}\right)
  &= \exp\left(\frac{2\pi p}w\right) \\
\frac\pi4 + \frac d2\cdot\frac\pi{180}
  &= \arctan\exp\left(\frac{2\pi p}w\right) \\
\frac d2\cdot\frac\pi{180}
  &= \arctan\exp\left(\frac{2\pi p}w\right) - \frac\pi4 \\
d  &= \frac{360}\pi \left(\arctan\exp\left(\frac{2\pi p}w\right) - \frac\pi4\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Awesome!!!  But I found one mistake when I checked it.  360/pi should be multiplied by pi/4 as well.  I fixed that one part and it worked flawlessly.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @DR01D You're right! Silly mistake forgetting the parentheses, but I've fixed that for the benefit of anyone else who happens to look at this.

Comment: If you hadn't provided the steps I would have never been able to spot that.  Also by going through your steps I learned a lot!